# Run JavaScript unit tests inside of Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have been searching for a good way to run JavaScript unit tests inside of the Visual Studio IDE.  I currently use [TestDriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/) to run my C# units tests and it is very convenient to be able to quickly get the result of my tests in the output pane. I would love to find a similar experience for JavaScript (ideally working with TestDriven.net).

I have read about different solutions that let you execute JavaScrpt unit tests.  Some have their own JS engine while others like [JS-Test-Driver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) are able to send the code to the browsers and fetch the results.  But I have yet to see something that is integrated into VS.

Does anyone know of an extension that might do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After nine months there are now a couple answers to this question.

I [created](http://matthewmanela.com/blog/chutzpah-a-javascript-test-runner-released/) an open source project called [Chutzpah - A JavaScript Test Runner](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah). Chutzpah enables you to run JavaScript unit tests from the command line and from inside of Visual Studio. It also supports running in the TeamCity continuous integration server.

Another solution is part of the next version of Resharper. In Resharper 6 there is an [integrated QUnit test runner](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/03/resharper-6-introduces-support-for-javascript-unit-testing/).

Comment: Nice step there to create your own test-runner :). Looks quite interesting.

I've personally kept with jstestdriver, given that it's just AWESOME at cross browser testing with build server. Also for developing, it's great with the snappy jsautotest wrapper that runs all tests on every save. [jstdutil_a_ruby_wrapper_over_jstestdriver](http://cjohansen.no/en/javascript/jstdutil_a_ruby_wrapper_over_jstestdriver)

Comment: Thanks, I definitely took a long look at jstestdriver and its ability to run across multiple browsers is very desirable. I plan to eventually add the ability to Chutzpah to use jstestdriver and possibly other test drivers. For the first release I went with a headless browser because it is self contained. A user can grab the bits and just run and not worry about what browser are on there machine.

Comment: @Matthew Manela That's great! :)

Comment: This is awesome. Just FYI for other people using this, if your scripts are in a different project, you might want to add something like this to your test project Pre-build events: XCOPY "$(SolutionDir)My.Web\Scripts" "$(ProjectDir)Scripts" /S /Y

Comment: Another benefit to Chutzpah is that it is supposed to handle async tests which you couldn't use in jstestdriver.

Comment: @Matthew Manela. It is for VS 2010 also, because I haven't find VS 2010 in the list.

Comment: Support for VS 2010 was removed in the most recent release.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to use [JsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) to be a test-runner in Visual Studio. Once a server has been started, with browsers attached, one can run tests directly from within Visual Studio.

The Console-window will then give the output of the test results. I won't go to implementation details here, but [the following how-to](http://slmoloch.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-run-jstestdriver-with-visual_02.html) should be enough to get you started on the actual setup of Visual Studio / JsTestRunner.

Console output from chrome and internet explorer (ignore my bad test-names): [image: Console output from chrome and internet explorer]

JsTestDriver is mainly a test-running tool to verify multiple browsers. To get good unit-tests on the javascript itself, one can plug in other test-specific tools like [JasmineBDD](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) ([jasmine to jstestdriver adapter](https://github.com/ibolmo/jasmine-jstd-adapter)).

JsTestDriver also opens up for the possibility to test against multiple browsers as a build step on your continuous integration server ie: Hudson ([Continuous Integration with Hudson and jstestdriver](http://cjohansen.no/en/javascript/javascript_continuous_integration_with_hudson_and_jstestdriver)). This then allows a dev to test against a certain browser or two while developing locally, but then verify the result against any range of OS / browser combinations on the build server.

Comment: That is pretty good.  It would be nice if this could be integrated inside of existing testing tools like TD.net or Resharper's test runner.  Another issue is that it is a bit slow (it has to launch the browsers and attach to them).  It would be cool if there was an option similar to http://www.envjs.com/ with an API we could hook into existing test runners.

Comment: During local development, you could just have the browsers open and attached to the server...allows for faster running. Still a drwaback that it runs ALL the tests, and not just the tests in the current context.

Comment: I'm hoping to look into hooking this up into TD.net. It ccertainly something that might be worthwhile. I haven't used envjs actually, so not sure how this actually works

Answer (score 1):

Just found this article (and this question) when looking for the same thing.

[Integrating JavaScript Unit Tests with Visual Studio - Steven Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/12/20/integrating-javascript-unit-tests-with-visual-studio.aspx)

It does have a lot of work onto it, but it seems that it really brings a nice interaction. For sure worth the hassle if you're working on a JavaScript heavy application.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a link recommending the use a NodeJS app to run our JavaScript Unit Tests. Visual Studio's test window can now see tests we write in that project even when the overall project is in C#:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/unit-testing-javascript-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019&tabs=mocha

One of the testing library combos (unit testing / mocking / assertions) recommended is using Mocha / Sinon / Chai. For this flavor there's a useful tutorial located here:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-test-nodejs-apps-using-mocha-chai-and-sinonjs

And another link for getting vanilla JS to work in the node environment:

- https://dev.to/thawkin3/how-to-unit-test-html-and-vanilla-javascript-without-a-ui-framework-4io